# Question not in English

Tags: discussion, off-topic

This question has multiple issues:

[Phpmyadmin erreur de l'ors de l'ouverture](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126389/phpmyadmin-erreur-de-lors-de-louverture)

First and most obviously, it's not in English. Not entirely sure what to flag it as under such circumstances.

Secondly, I think (from what I can gather with my limited French), it would be a better fit (if it was in English) on ServerFault. I don't want to flag it as needing migrating, because they won't want a question not in English either.

What's the policy/expected actions for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a question is not in English it should be closed as "unclear what you're asking". With a few obvious exceptions, Stack Exchange sites are expected to be in English.

At that point the content itself becomes irrelevant. Whether it is on-topic or could possibly be migrated to another site (assuming it meets their standards for question quality) is moot. However, if the question is updated to be in English, it can be reopened, and migrated, if it meets the quality standards of the appropriate network site.

Comment: Assuming it is a language we can identify, should we use an online interpreter and edit the question to add the English translation? It may also be moot if the OP cannot understand English, but perhaps worth a try. What is your opinion? Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc That tricky for the reason you mentioned. When they are clearly off-topic it's an easy call but if it is salvageable by translating it, will the OP be able to understand the answers? One train of thought is to go ahead and do it as it will be valuable to future users. Maybe that's enough to make it worthwhile?

Comment: No matter what, it will be a bit of a crap shoot, however, if someone was so inclined, it could be a shot in the dark that may have value. If not, then it was shot none-the-less. Nothing ventured, nothing gained. Now are there any other worn out cliche's I could throw in this comment? I think not! Cheers!!

Comment: I translated it. I assume it can be migrated if you want. If the OP can understand the answers is not up to us. I suspect server fault may close it again. Who knows? At least we are one step closer to something or nothing.

Comment: I only hesitate to migrate it as "bad migrations" are very much frowned upon. When I read that question I am unsure if there is enough information in the question for someone to effectively diagnose the issue.

Comment: Good point! Cheers!!